# Controller does not exist using Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created the Laravel project and I uploaded it into a shared server. Inside the server, I tested the application some controllers are not working but in the local, I tested it's working without issues.

When I tested the application in server it's saying

```
ReflectionException (-1)
Class Asset_Management_System\Http\Controllers\SublocOneController 
does not exist
```

I don't know what was the issue please help me to fix this issue.

Controller File

```
namespace Asset_Management_System\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Asset_Management_System\MainLocation;
use Asset_Management_System\SubLocationOne;

class SubLocOneController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

Web.php file

```
Route::resource('SubLocationOne','SubLocOneController');
```

Comment: typo? "SublocOneController" is not the same as "SubLocOneController"

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect via ssh to the server and run in the root of the site:

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u renaming the app file in laravel structure with Asset_Management_System ?

1. basically if u make controller with this path : 
   `App\Http\Controllers\[YourControllerName];`

1.1 just do this :
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

2. In other case, you can use `composer dump-autoload` in terminal inside your directory.
3. Typo `SublocOneController` and `SubLocOneController`?